# Imports cannot be resolved - Visual Studio Code for Java

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

I am working on a Java project which is managed by Maven.

The project actually is composed of three *sub-projects*:
- Backend
- Builder
- Frontend

Every single of those projects is Maven based and the Builder works as a *bridge* between Frontend and backend.
In fact the Builder is the parent project for all of them.
The `pom.xml` of the **Builder** is as follows:

```
...
<modules>
    <module>Model</module>
</modules>
...
```

Whereas the **Model** has `pom.xml` like this:

```
  ...
  <parent>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>Builder</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.0</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>Model</artifactId>
  <build>
    *Backend build directives*      
  </build>
  ...
```

The **problem** is that from Visual studio Code i can build every single module successfully without errors but the code editor gives me "*import cannot be resolved*.." wherever i have dependecies towards **backend**.
I came to think that this is a bug of the "Java Language Support by RedHat" which cannot find dependencies ...
Has this happened to anybody?

**--- Edit 28/11/2019 ---**

I forgot to clearify that all of the **Builder's dependencies** (so towards Backend and other Util libraries) are resolved correctly as I can see those Jars inside **Frontend's** resolved dependencies folder.

Comment: Could you provide the actual error given from your code editor?

Comment: @Josh actually every dependency towards some class of backend is not resolved so it is shown as an error .. but as I said maven builds everthying successfully

Answer (score 0):

you could try like this:

in your parent project pom.xml:

```
<groupId>com.blackr</groupId>
<artifactId>cloudtest</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

in your child project pom.xml:

```
<artifactId>module</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.blackr</groupId>
    <artifactId>cloudtest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../parent/pom.xml</relativePath> //Location of the parent project's pom.xml file
</parent>
```

Comment: Unfortunately inserting the tag "<relativePath>" inside child's pom.xml doesn't change anything .. Actually the strange thing is that i have some dependencies that are inserted inside Builder module and after the build of the Frontend module i can see that inside "Maven dependencies" there are all of the required Jars for the Frontend module so the hierarchy dependencies are resolved correctly at Frontend's build time